Entity Framework Core : join comma-separated list
I'm using EF Core to model an old legacy database. One table uses a comma separated list to reference another table instead of a proper foreign key. How can I model this with EF as a navigation property?
Tables:
recipe                         ingredient

id  | ingredients              id  | name
----+--------------            ----+----------
 1  | "1,2,3"                   1  | "flour"
 2  | "3,4"                     2  | "sugar" 
 3  | "2"                       3  | "egg"
 4  | "1,2,3,4"                 4  | "butter"

EF classes:
public class Recipe
{
    [Column("id")]
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}

    [Column("ingredients")]
    public string IngredientIds {get; set;}

    // How to implement this?
    public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients {get; set;}
}

public class Ingredient
{
    [Column("id")]
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}

    [Column("name")]
    public string Name {get; set;}

    // This would also be nice to have
    public virtual ICollection<Recipe> Recipes{get; set;}
}


Is this really a SQL language question? (I see no SQL above, do you expect a SQL answer?)

Sample data is great, but can you also specify the expected? I.e. provide a complete [mcve].

Can you elaborate? The expected is that ingredients would be joinable with include, as they would if the tables were joined using a proper foreign key.

To check, do you have the option to refactor your database / to create a RecipeIngredient table with columns RecipeId & IngredientId to create this association?  It'll give much better performance & will help avoid various pitfalls (e.g. ensuring unique entries for recipe-ingredient pairs); so is the better route to go down vs adding a workaround solution on top of a bad implementation.

Unfortunately I cannot modify the database, as there are other applications using the same database. Otherwise that would obviously be the "correct" answer.

Please show your efforts and show where you're stuck. That said, it's impossible to create a navigation property for this.

Simple short, it is not possible.

Can this not be done using C# Linq Inner Join?   (Sorry, I am too new to C# to get this done... )

This is a terrible design, impossible to index or search. You could use a computed property that maps to an expression using regexp_split_to_array to convert this to an array but you can't define relations on this. Even with manually written SQL you'd have to use some tricky operands to JOIN between an ID and the contents of an array

To bring this question to a conclusion: no this isn't possible. EF navigation properties can be defined between scalar properties in an equals relationship, not contains.
Contains would be problematic anyway, because a more realistic example like "251,21223,1453,21569" would match a large range of Id values, most of them unintended: 2, 5, 25, 251, 21, 212, ... (you get the picture).
You are aware that this is bad design. To make this a little bit workable, and if it's allowed to add views to the database, you could consider adding a view like this one (in SQL Server, but there are equivalents in other database providers):
CREATE VIEW IngredientsWithRecipeId
AS
SELECT ing.Id
    , ing.Name
    , r.Id AS RecipeId
FROM [dbo].[Recipe] r
OUTER APPLY string_split(r.[IngredientIds] ,',') AS ids
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Ingredient] ing ON ids.value = ing.Id

Then you could map an entity to it in EF and use navigation properties based on this view.
Obviously, the view does not return any rows for non-existing Id values in IngredientIds, but that's a consequence of this design totally lacking any referential integrity. Also, its performance is likely to be incurably poor.

PostgreSQL doesn't have STRING_SPLIT. The equivalents are string_to_table and string_to_array.

@PanagiotisKanavos: PostgreSQL is not mentioned in this question, it is only mentioned in the other question about same subject ....

I thought there was only one question! If the OP expects a different answer by posting essentially the same question they'll be disappointed

@PanagiotisKanavos I knew about the other question. This one is specifically about how to create a navigation property. After comments saying: can't do, OP decided to ask a more generic question. I think that's valid.

The more I think about it, it may be possible to improve things with NpgSql and PostgreSQL magic. Which I haven't ever tried. A index on string_to_array(IngredientIds) to accelerate  EF.Functions.StringToArray(recipe.IngredientIds).All(ingredientIds) in LINQ. And hoping the optimizer will use the index...
